# How to get the last element of Object into Same Object

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public class RequestTest
{
    public InnerException innerException { get; set; }
}

public class InnerException 
{
    public string text{ get; set;}
    public  InnerException innerException { get; set; }
}
```

I have a object into same object of same type recursirve, how to get last innerException object?

sample:

```
var request= new RequestTest()
        {
            innerException = new InnerException()
            {
                message = "inner 1",
                innerException = new InnerException()
                {
                    message = "inner 2"
                }
            }
        };
```

how to get last element? "inner 2"

Comment: You mean `root.innerException.innerException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recursion with a methode like this

```
public InnerException GetDeepest(InnerException inner)
{
    if(inner.innerException == null)return inner;
    return GetDeepest(inner.innerException);
}
```

To us simply call `var deepestInner = GetDeepest(request.InnerException);`

The methode will check if there is a `innerException` is so it will call it self with to get the deeper one, if not `inner` is the deepest

Answer (score 2):

Recurse and re-assign the variable until you reach a `null` InnerException.  Then you know you are at the last valid one.

```
var ex = request.InnerException;
while(ex.InnerException != null)
{
    ex = ex.InnerException;
}
```